# retrieve value of cell that has formula

Tags: epplus

I have an excel template file with formulas, I access it with epplus , I load a table to a group of cells and I update ranges of two formula cells, then I execute the calculate of the sheet and when I want to retrieve the value of the fields with formulas It doesn't bring me the values.

I have noticed that when opening the file the formulas are not executed and it takes time to show the values, then I modify the formulas with Excel itself, I try again to read the values ​​from the app and I can read them. I don't understand why this scenario